# React/NextJS: Loading an external script only for non-authenticated users

Tags: reactjs, next.js

We're attempting to load an ad script - but only if a user is non-authenticated.
Note: We are using Next.js

Here is how we're loading the ad script at the moment (note, this is a condensed example).

```
const AdContext = createContext()
export default AdContext
export const useAd = () => useContext(AdContext)

export const AdProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { currentUserIsSilverPlus } = useAuth()

  const loadAds = useCallback(() => {
    // ... Pushes ad blocks into divs/ad placement area...
  }, [currentUserIsSilverPlus])

  const contextValues = { loadAds }

  return (
    <AdContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
      <Script
        type="text/javascript"
        src={`//external-script.js`}
        data-cfasync="false"
        onLoad={loadAds}
      />
      {children}
    </AdContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't quite work because when the page initially loads, currentUserIsSilverPlus is set as false (and then quickly switches to true).

```
  if(!currentUserIsSilverPlus) {
    return (
        <AdContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
          <Script
            type="text/javascript"
            src={`//monu.delivery/site/a/9/598bde-eb57-4f38-a35e-8d84df26769e.js`}
            data-cfasync="false"
            onLoad={loadAds}
          />
          {children}
        </AdContext.Provider>
      )
  } else {
    return (
        <AdContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
          {children}
        </AdContext.Provider>
      )
  }
}
```

I also tried moving the script load into useEffect, but the same issue occurred - with the script always load.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(!currentUserIsSilverPlus) {
    return (
        <Script
        type="text/javascript"
        src={`//external-script.js`}
        data-cfasync="false"
        onLoad={loadAds}
      />
    )
   }
  }, [currentUserIsSilverPlus])
  
  return (
    <AdContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
      {loadAdScript()}
      {children}
    </AdContext.Provider>
  )
```

How can I get the script to only load when currentUserIsSilverPlus is True (despite it being initially False on load).

Edit: Adding auth code at request of a commenter.

```
const AuthContext = createContext()

export default AuthContext

export const AuthProvider = ({ children, isProtected = false }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [userLoaded, setUserLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)
  const [currentUserRole, setCurrentUserRule] = useState("Free - Bronze")
  const [currentUserIsSilverPlus, setCurrentUserIsSilverPlus] = useState(false)
  const [currentUserIsGoldPlus, setCurrentUserIsGoldPlus] = useState(false)
  const [currentUserIsDiamondPlus, setCurrentUserIsDiamondPlus] =
    useState(false)
  const [hyvorSSO, setHyvorSSO] = useState({})
  const [emailHasBeenSent, setEmailHasBeenSent] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()

  const updateUserInfo = useCallback(async user => {
    setHyvorSSO(HYVOR_TALK_CONFIG.sso)
    setCurrentUser(user)
    setUserLoaded(true)
    if (user) {
      const stripeRole = await getUserStripeRole(user)
      if (stripeRole) {
        setCurrentUserRule(stripeRole)
        setCurrentUserIsSilverPlus(true)
      }
      if (stripeRole === "PRO-Gold") {
        setCurrentUserIsSilverPlus(true)
        setCurrentUserIsGoldPlus(true)
      }
      if (stripeRole === "PRO-Diamond") {
        setCurrentUserIsSilverPlus(true)
        setCurrentUserIsGoldPlus(true)
        setCurrentUserIsDiamondPlus(true)
      }
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    registerUserUpdateEventListener(updateUserInfo)
  }, [updateUserInfo])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isProtected && userLoaded && !currentUser) router.push("/login")
  }, [isProtected, userLoaded, currentUser, router])

  const contextValues = {
    currentUser,
    currentUserRole,
    currentUserIsSilverPlus,
    currentUserIsGoldPlus,
    currentUserIsDiamondPlus,
    hyvorSSO,
    emailHasBeenSent,
    userLoaded,
    isNotLoggedIn: userLoaded && !currentUser,
    signUp,
    signIn,
    signOut,
    manageAccount,
    resetPassword: resetUserPassword,
    sendVerificationEmail,
    changeEmail,
    startCheckoutSession,
  }

  if (loading || (isProtected && !userLoaded)) return <LoaderBaseball />

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `useAuth` code, too? That would help to identify your problem

Comment: @NickVu - I added a condensed version of it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `userLoaded` before checking `currentUserIsSilverPlus`

```
const AdContext = createContext()
export default AdContext
export const useAd = () => useContext(AdContext)

export const AdProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { currentUserIsSilverPlus, userLoaded } = useAuth()

  const loadAds = useCallback(() => {
    // ... Pushes ad blocks into divs/ad placement area...
  }, [currentUserIsSilverPlus])

  const contextValues = { loadAds }

  
  //if user data is not loaded yet, we don't need to have that script
  //and in the meanwhile, we also check `currentUserIsSilverPlus`  
  return (
    <AdContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
      {userLoaded && !currentUserIsSilverPlus && <Script
        type="text/javascript"
        src={`//external-script.js`}
        data-cfasync="false"
        onLoad={loadAds}
      />}
      {children}
    </AdContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue. I'm starting to think that next/script gets "injected" into the DOM - so once it's there, it needs to be manually removed.

Comment: Did you try to put `console.log` to check `userLoaded ` value? I think it'd help to narrow down where problem is @JeremyE